# Equality in spectral inclusion theorem

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, semigroups-of-operators

I asked this question on [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3683600/385720) but didn't receive any response.

Let $(T_t)$ be a $C_0$-semigroup on a Banach space $X$ with generator $A.$ If $\lambda_0\in \mathbb{C}$ is such that $e^{\lambda_0 t}$ is a pole of $R(\cdot,T(t)),$ then $\lambda_0$ is a pole of $R(\cdot,A)$ and $$k(e^{\lambda_0 t},T(t))\geq k(\lambda_0,A)\tag{1}$$ where $k(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the order of the corresponding pole. This is proved for example in Theorem IV.3.6 in the [book by Engel and Nagel](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b97696).

**My question:** Suppose we a priori know that $\lambda_0$ is a pole of $R(\cdot,A)$ and $e^{\lambda_0 t}$ is a pole of $R(\cdot,T(t))$ for all $t\geq 0.$ Are there any *known* conditions which guarantee an equality in $(1)$ for at least some $t>0?$

Comment: I would suspect that eventual compactness of the semigroup suffices to get equality for some times $t$ by a functional calaculus argument, but one would have to check the details. For more general semigroups, things might get more involved...

Comment: @JochenGlueck Do you know of a reference where similar arguments are used? Say for an eventually compact semigroup, how would one go about proving this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know a reference, but the main line of argument should be as follows: Choose a right half plane $H$ that contains $\lambda_0$, then split off the part of the spectrum of $A$ that is contained in $H$ by means of a spectral projection. This reduces the problem to a finite dimensional situation, so one can use matrix analysis to prove the claim.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Reducing to finite dimensions make sense but how would one go about applying this to $R(\cdot,T(t))?$ Would using $R(\lambda,A)=R(e^{\lambda t},T(t)) \int_0^t e^{\lambda(t-s)}T(s) \ ds$ help?

Comment: In finite dimensions, the problem is essentially about the size of Jordan blocks. If I find time, I'll post the details in an answer this weekend.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Yes one needs to show that size of the largest Jordan block is at most $k(\lambda_0,A).$

Comment: Exactly -- and this follows immediately if you choose $t$ such that $\lambda \mapsto e^{t \lambda}$ maps all finitely many spectral values of $A$ on your finite dimensional space to distinct numbers. Does this answer your question, or should I add some more details?

Comment: @JochenGlueck I'd be grateful if you could add more details in an answer. I don't see how to achieve this.

Comment: Alright. About what point precisely are you unsure?

Comment: @JochenGlueck Mainly how to use eventual compactness of semigroup. Also is this technique of restricting to the finite-dimensional situations and using Jordan blocks common? It would be great if I could read similar arguments to get more understanding.

Comment: Reducing problems to the finite dimensional case is a quite common approach in spectral theory whenever sufficient compactness if present. (In my answer I've included a reference to a Corollary in the book of Engel and Nagel where you can see this in detail). Using Jordan blocks is probably the simplest way to understand the functional calculus in finite dimensions, so it is very common in the study of the matrix exponential function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a positive solution if the semigroup is eventually compact:

Consider, say, the open right halfplane
$$
  H := \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}: \, \operatorname{Re}\lambda > \operatorname{Re}\lambda_0 - 1\}.
$$
Then $H$ contains only finitely many spectral values of $A$, and all these spectral values are poles of the resolvent with finite-rank spectral projections. So if we denote the sum of these finitely many spectral projections by $P$, then the range $PX$ is a finite dimensional space, and the restriction of the semigroup to the complementary subspace $\ker P$ only contains spectral values with real part $\le \operatorname{Re}\lambda_0 - 1$.

All these properties follow from Corollary V.3.2 in the semigroup book of Engel and Nagel (2000).

The restriction of the semigroup to $\ker P$ is also eventually compact, so the spectral mapping theorem holds for it [op. cit., Corollary IV.3.12(i)]. Hence, $e^{t\lambda_0}$ is not in the spectrum of $T_t|_{\ker P}$ for any $t$.

So we only need to deal with the restriction of the semigroup to the finite dimensional space $PX$. Hence, we may asume from now on that $X$ itself is finite dimensional and that $A$ is a matrix. After a coordinate transformation, $A$ is in Jordan normal form. The matrix $A$ has distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_0, \dots, \lambda_m$, and for each $k \in \{0, \dots, m\}$ there are Jordan blocks $J_{k,1}, \dots, J_{k,\ell_k}$.

Since $A$ is the direct sum of all these Jordan blocks, we can compute $e^{tA}$ by computing $e^{tJ_{k,i}}$ for all Jordan blocks separately.

Now, if $t \in [0,\infty)$ is such that the numbers $e^{t\lambda_0}, \dots, e^{t\lambda_m}$ are all distinct, then out of all direct summands
$$
  e^{tJ_{0,1}} , \dots, e^{tJ_{0,\ell_0}} , \quad \dots \quad , e^{tJ_{m,1}}, \dots, e^{tJ_{m,\ell_m}}
$$
of $e^{tA}$, only the matrices $e^{tJ_{0,1}} , \dots, e^{tJ_{0,\ell_0}}$ have the eigenvalue $e^{t\lambda_0}$. Hence, the dimension of largest Jordan block in $e^{tA}$ that belongs to the eigenvalue $e^{t\lambda_0}$ (i.e., the order of the pole $e^{t\lambda_0}$ of $R(\cdot,e^{tA})$) cannot be larger than the largest dimension of the matrices $e^{tJ_{0,1}} , \dots, e^{tJ_{0,\ell_0}}$ - which is the same as the largest dimension of the matrices $J_{0,1}, \dots, J_{0,\ell_0}$ (and this is, in turn, the order the pole $\lambda_0$ of $R(\cdot,A)$).

This solves the question for all those times $t$ for which the numbers $e^{t\lambda_0}, \dots, e^{t\lambda_m}$ are distinct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one question. Firstly, it seems to me that what you really used was SMT and not eventual compactness directly. So your proof technically works for all semigroups for which SMT holds? In particular, it holds for eventually norm continuous semigroups?

Comment: @Mark: Well, I used that there are only finitely many spectral values in the half plane $H$ and that these are poles of the resolvent with finite dimensional spectral spaces. But you are probably right that we can do better than that: If the semigroup is merely eventually norm continuous, and the spectral projection $P_0$ associated to the pole $\lambda_0$ has, say, finite rank, then I think it should work to merely split off $P_0$: if $t > 0$ is sufficiently small, than $T_t|_{\ker P_0}$ won't have $e^{t\lambda_0}$ in its spectrum (due to the spectral mapping theorem), and we're fine.

Comment: @Mark: If the spectral space $P_0X$ is not finite dimensional, though, then the reduction to matrix analysis does no longer work, of course. I'd be optimistic that the same result about the pole order still holds, but one would have to think about the details in the infinite dimensional case.